# Silverlight 5 Out of Brower with Elevated Trust application with MEF

Tags: silverlight, mef, typeloadexception

I want to use MEF in a Silverlight 5 Out of Browser application with Elevated Privileges.

I am having issues when using MEF and getting the exception when the following line of code is being executed

```
CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
```

> {System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while
>   overriding member: 'System.Exception.get_InnerException()'. Security
>   accessibility of the overriding method must match the security
>   accessibility of the method being overriden.
>
> Excemption Message says Inheritance security rules violated while
>   overriding member: 'System.Exception.get_InnerException()'. Security
>   accessibility of the overriding method must match the security
>   accessibility of the method being overriden.

I have tried downloading couple of MEF samples from internet.  All were silverlight 4 applications.  I converted the application to use Silverlight 5 runtime and the application fails at he above line of code mentioned.

This is what I found on silverlight.net [forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/238126.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid error which I also had, what worked for me was I changed the Target framework of my shell project to Silverlight 4, ran it, saw it work, then changed back to Silverlight 5 and it still worked.